# live stream with ffmpeg and IP camera

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I'm reading a live stream from a DKSEG IP camera, but the results are not good at all ...

Here is the command line used for this :

```
./ffmpeg -i "http://192.168.0.29/videostream.asf?user=admin&pwd=&resolution=64&rate=0" \
-vcodec libx264 -r 20 -s 320x240 -threads 2 -vprofile baseline -vpre zoom \
-strict experimental -acodec aac -ab 96000 -ar 48000 -ac 1 \
-f rtsp rtsp://54.232.999.999:1935/live/_definst_/c3
```

the zoom.ffpreset :

```
coder=1
level=31
maxrate=1200000
bufsize=200000
wpredp=0
g=60
refs=1
subq=3
trellis=0
bf=0
rc_lookahead=0
```

Even when I save to a mp4 file the results are not good, with some gaps in the video.
Any toughts ? suggestions ?

Here is the output of the execution (thanks @lordneckbeard) :

```
ffmpeg version 2.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 15 2013 10:56:46 with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      52. 38.100 / 52. 38.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 79.101 /  3. 79.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, asf, from 'http://192.168.0.29/videostream.asf?user=admin&pwd=&resolution=64&rate=0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p, 640x480, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_ima_wav ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 8000 Hz, mono, s16p, 32 kb/s
Codec AVOption rc_lookahead (Number of frames to look ahead for alternate reference frame selection) specified for output file #0 (rtsp://54.232.999.999:1935/live/_definst_/c3) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
No pixel format specified, yuvj420p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x7fd73b82fa00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x7fd73b82fa00] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7fd73b82fa00] 264 - core 133 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=3 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=2 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=60 keyint_min=6 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=1200 vbv_bufsize=200 crf_max=0.0 nal_hrd=none ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, rtsp, to 'rtsp://54.232.999.999:1935/live/_definst_/c3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuvj420p, 320x240, q=-1--1, 90k tbn, 20 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (adpcm_ima_wav -> aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Multiple frames in a packet from stream 1
frame=  986 fps= 43 q=28.0 size=N/A time=00:00:49.38 bitrate=N/A dup=811 drop=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Where did the zoom preset come from? Why do you use that instead of a standard [x264 preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)? What do you mean by "gaps" in the video? Do the default settings provide a good output? Try `ffmpeg -i http://input -c:v libx264 -an output.mp4` (notice the local output file to test instead of RTMP for now).

Comment: will try tomorrow :)

Comment: saved the result here, https://www.dropbox.com/s/30xvg7oordbe3zd/output%20%281%29.mp4 note that from second 06 -> 09 is frozen, coould be network issue or camera issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. Can anything play the input stream like ffplay or vlc? If it also shows the same issues then it is probably not a problem on the encoding side.

Comment: tested with VLC and the streaming work without any issues ... :\ I heard about some issues with the tcp implementation of ffmpeg could this be the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can test with `ffplay` or via `ffmpeg` with [sdl](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#sdl) or [xv](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#xv) (maybe not xv on OS X) output devices.